# Error msg : {"code":"BadRequest","message":"The server did not understand the operation that was requested.","type":"client"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get the list of userpools in aws cognito this error code arrises

Host URL: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ListUserPools?Version=2016-04-18

I am using postman it calculates aws signature correctly so no problem in that...

AWS ListUserPools : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUserPools.html

Where to place that request syntax on the documentation link ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either use the AWS CLI or any of the AWS SDKs to make this call. You can't just do it using postman. Scroll down to the documentation link you have [posted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUserPools.html). Now select any of the SDKs that you want to develop using. Then follow the documentation for that language.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply,  I tried using java SDK it worked, but I need to use rest api for listing user pools is there is any way to do soo...

Comment: I think you need to add a hosted UI for that. For more information you can go through the following documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-userpools-server-contract-reference.html

Comment: Yes I tried using that api's in the documentation you have provided, which helps in authorizing users in cognito user pools, but I need to get informations about userpools using rest api.... Is there any way for than.....

Comment: You can get info about your own user. For all users you need to use signed calls which you can do in backend. so you will need sdk for that.

Comment: yes,I used java sdk for fetching all users in all userpools it worked fine. But they provied rest api to do the same I need to know how to do that using rest api([ListUserPools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUserPools.html))....

Comment: No problem. If it solves your problem please don't forget to mark as correct

Comment: I am also looking for how to do this WITHOUT an SDK. Just pure HTTP API. Did you find it completely impossible?